# Como obtener parte de una url de un string en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar quiero obtener valor de un `string`.
             Siempre quiero obtener el parámetro despues de `&VariableR=` 
             ahora estoy realizando este codigo pero solo me obtiene dos digitos pero quisiera obtener todo siempre y cuando este depues de `&VariableR=`.

```
string Strings = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";
int indice1 = strings.IndexOf("&VariableR=") + "&VariableR=".Length;
//Resultado me sale 85
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Es tan simple como hacer:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://www.example.com?param1=good&param2=bad");
string param1 = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("param1");
```

Con eso obtendrías el valor de `param1` para la URL de ejemplo planteada.

Para utilizar el método de arriba deberás hacer: `using System.Web;`

---

En tu caso se aplicaría de la siguiente forma:

```
string Strings = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";
Uri theUri = new Uri(Strings);
string paramValue = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(theUri.Query).Get("VariableR");
```

---

Si quieres hacerlo un poco más genérico, puedes volverlo un método:

```
public static string GetParameterFromUrl(string url, string paramname)
{
    return HttpUtility.ParseQueryString((new Uri(url)).Query).Get(paramname) ?? null;
}
```

Y lo llamarías de la siguiente forma:

```
string Strings = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";
string VariableR = GetParameterFromUrl(Strings, "VariableR");
```

Enlaces de utilidad:

- [Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)
- [Un fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wNduuM)

Comment: @naCI te lo agradesco muchoo..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo, como deseas a nivel de string (como lo planteaste desde un principio)

```
string myStrings = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";
int indice1 = myStrings.IndexOf("&VariableR=") + "&VariableR=".Length;

string code = myStrings.Substring(indice1);
```

Con esto respondería tu pregunta, pero para tu caso la mejor opción es la mencionada en otra respuesta, haciendo uso de `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

Answer (score 0):

¿por donde empiezo ?

tu codigo no te esta trayendo los dos primeros digitos. lo que tu codigo te esta devolviendo es la longitud de tu variable string hasta &VariableR que da la coincidencia que es 85

estubiste muy cerca de terminarlo con este acercamiento, solo tenias que agregar el substring :

```
        string Strings = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";
        int indice1 = Strings.IndexOf("&VariableR=") + "&VariableR=".Length;
        string ValorVariable = Strings.Substring(indice1, (Strings.Length - indice1));
        Console.WriteLine(ValorVariable);
```

ahora... para una mejor respuesta:

Estas obteniendo los parámetros desde la url del navegador o desde una variable ?

para obtener los parámetros "Get" de un request solamente necesitas utilizar Request.QueryString

```
 string ValorVariable = Request.QueryString["VariableR"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes utilizar la función `Split` para obtener este último parámetro de tu URL.

```
string Cadena = "http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=853199";


var param = Cadena.Split('=').Last();

Console.WriteLine(param);
```

Luego para comprobar de que verdaderamente tiene este parametro luego del R= puedes utilizar un

```
if(param != null) Acciones
```

Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y si `=` es parte de un string codificado en [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Comment: No parece que este sea el caso.