# Como obtener valor generado de una ruta boots en asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, robots.txt

Buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar.

quiero obtener el parametro que envia un bot.

segun me informan esta es la ruta.

http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin

pero cuando el bots genera se genera algo asi.

http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin&VariableR=878479

siempre con una variable VariableR

ese valor quisiera obtener en el asp.net webform.

Comment: ¿No es la misma pregunta que has hecho anteriormente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/182835/como-obtener-parte-de-una-url-de-un-string-en-asp-net-c ?

Comment: @byte96 no porque el otro era extraer un valor de un string pero el otro es que la variable no se y quisiera obtener

Comment: mira mi respuesta :  string ValorVariable = Request.QueryString["VariableR"];

Comment: @Mike hermano esa vez era porque ya conocia la variable r pero ahora solo me dan este link : http://alianzas.qapaq.pe/PlataformaGestion/Gestion/?ref=Affiliate_AskRobin y un bott genera &VariableR=878479

cuando yo pongo igual como la rspta de la otra consulta si se dan cuenta ahora no esta el parametro VariableR

Comment: que quiere decir que un bot genera el resto? si vos no recibis eso, como vas a saber que sacar?